# Writing a method in ruby that only acts on a collection of a Class

Tags: ruby, collections, methods

Is there a may to write an instance method that only operates on a collection of the class?

So for example say I have something like this:

```
class Foo
    def collection_method
      puts "I only work on a collection of Foo!"
    end
end

@foos = []

5.times {@foos << Foo.new}

@foo = Foo.new

@foos.collection_method  #=> I only work on a collection of Foo!
@foo.collection_method #=> Some sort of expection or error
```

Comment: The use case of this is odd. A collection of Foos is not a Foo so putting the method in Foo seems like the wrong place.  Making your use case more clear would help considerably in getting a good answer. 

Also, it's not very rubyish to constrain calls to a given class, if the object quacks and waddles like a duck you should be able to treat it as a duck.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has no concept of "collections of a certain object", but you can easily monkey-patch in a method on `Array` that only works when all items in the array are of your type.

```
irb(main):001:0> class Foo
irb(main):002:1>  def bar
irb(main):003:2>   puts "bar"
irb(main):004:2>  end
irb(main):005:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):006:0>
irb(main):007:0* class Array
irb(main):008:1>  def collection_method
irb(main):009:2>   raise "Not all Foo objects" unless self.all? { |x| x.instance_of? Foo }
irb(main):010:2>   self[0].bar
irb(main):011:2>  end
irb(main):012:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):013:0> [1,2,3].collection_method
RuntimeError: Not all Foo objects
        from (irb):9:in `collection_method'
        from (irb):13
        from ♥:0
irb(main):014:0> [Foo.new, Foo.new].collection_method
bar
=> nil
```

But this really goes against the grain of a dynamic language.  It would be more natural to just try it out (whatever you're doing) and deal with errors as they arise.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, @foos is an Array. So you can :

- Add a method to Array

  ```
  class Array
    def collection_method
      ...
    end
  end
  ```
- Create your own "Array" Class

  ```
  class MyArray < Array
    def collection_method
      ...
    end
  end

  @foos = MyArray.new
  ...
  ```

I think that's the first solution is not the better one...